# Dry paint becoming lubricant with heat

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

I am undertaking a physics experiment and have come up with a chemistry problem. Could paint perhaps become a lubricant under mild temperature. (It would take a while to explain my experiment, but an object sliding down a ramp is increasing velocity with increasing mass, this should not happen if if coefficient of friction stays constant). I am wondering if anyone has information about paints lubrication vs temperature, or anything similar. The coefficient of friction is the same before and after the experiment, so I am wondering if paint changes its coefficient of friction or lubrication when temperature increases.

I'm sorry if this questions doesn't make sense, if anyone can point me towards anything paint and friction related, thankyou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take "paint" in the very broad meaning of substances used to treat surfaces:

wood can be waxed, and [waxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wax) melt at not too elevated temperature and can then behave like [oils](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oil).

I'd expect the behaviour of waxes here as very prone to surprises, since they can also become sticky when some compounds are liquid while others are solid.

Comment: Certainly skiers have opinions about skis and waxes! ;)

Comment: @EdV :-D never met anyone who really liked klister... But I think the grip wax, glide wax, liquid water (lubricant), snow/ice crystals system is quite a bit more complicated than what OP has here (giving room also for lots of opinions). At least I hope their system is easier...